# LDAP authentication NFS home mount with local login

Tags: ldap, nfs, mount

I have a configuration that normally user home is automatically mounted after ldap authentication. What I want to learn is how can I mount ldap authenticated nfs home of a user with local login? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `autofs` and `pam` function independently.

It will be enough to add the autofs entry such that the system that runs autofs can read it.

Comment: Can you briefly elaborate how can I do this?